# Why Static field can't be accessed through an instance

Tags: flutter, dart

Why Static field can't be accessed through an instance.
Dart 2.4 Flutter 1.7 Android Studio 3.4

When I was trying to port codes from JAVA to Flutter(Dart), I got the compile error

I had defined the variable in MyMainBloc as follows

```
static LoginStatus loginStatus = null;
```

Then I create an instance:

```
MyMainBloc myApp;
```

I expect to use something like this: myApp.loginStatus, NOT MyMainBloc.loginStatus.

Comment: Given `SomeClass object`, the type of `object` is statically known, so `object.someStaticMember` *could* be treated as syntactic sugar for `SomeClass.someStaticMember`.  That said, Dart 1 did not have static typing, so that perhaps is one reason why the language doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 2):

Static members of a particular class are accessed at the class level, not the object level. What this basically means is that the static variable is shared between objects.

With that in mind, what you are potentially attempting to do is probably not the best idea. Without seeing more of your code, you are probably better off declaring your loginStatus property as a private member on an encapsulating class, then accessing that member through a method (perhaps a standard get*() method).

The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) on class members could be of some help here.